# Sharepoint List conditional format if major version is published

Tags: json, sharepoint, format, conditional-statements

I am trying to conditional format my sharepoint list so that I highlight files that has been published, ie. version does not contain "0."

I could not find out to use wildcard, so the below code with "0." was replaced with "0.*" did not work.

Can I change the operator from "!=" to something else that means contains or not contains?

```
{
      "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
      "additionalRowClass": {
        "operator": ":",
        "operands": [
          {
            "operator": "!=",
            "operands": [
              "[$_UIVersionString]",
              "0."
            ]
          },
          "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-MintGreenFont",
          ""
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this JSON:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
    "additionalRowClass": "=if(indexOf([$_UIVersionString], '0.') >= 0, '', 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-MintGreenFont')"
}
```

**Documentation**: [SharePoint JSON formatting-syntax-reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference)

Comment: Would it be possible to ignore folders in the formatting? So only files will be colored.

Comment: You may need to add Content Type field in your list view then you can use expression like: `[$ContentType] != 'Folder'`. For more information, follow sample: https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/blob/master/column-samples/generic-download-file-button/generic-download-file-button.json